# Hash & Salt - Login different from Register

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I was trying to find out why my registration password entry is different than the digest on login...

They are never equal... I thought It was because I had 2 different base64 encoders but that was not it.

Here is the registration create user code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> register_Post(@RequestParam(value = "user", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "pass", required = true) String password,
            @RequestParam(value = "expire", required = true) String time) {
        if (userService.isExistant(username))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        User user = new User();
        try {
            user.setEmailAddress(username);
            user.setEmployer(false);
            user.setActive(false);
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            byte[] bSalt = new byte[8];
            random.nextBytes(bSalt);
            String sSalt = new String(Base64.encode(bSalt), "UTF-8");
            byte[] bDigest = SecurityUtils.getHash(SecurityUtils.ITERATION_NUMBER, password, bSalt);
            String sDigest = new String(Base64.encode(bDigest), "UTF-8");
            user.setPassword(sDigest);
            user.setSalt(sSalt);
            userService.updateUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Here is the login code:

```
byte[] bSalt = Base64.decode(candidate.getSalt().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] prospect = Base64.decode(candidate.getPassword().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] bDigest = SecurityUtils.getHash(SecurityUtils.ITERATION_NUMBER, password, bSalt);
            if (Arrays.equals(prospect, bDigest)) 
                  return true;
```

And here is the SecurityUtils code:

```
public class SecurityUtils {
     public final static int ITERATION_NUMBER = 1000;
     public static byte[] getHash(int iterationNb, String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
           MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
           digest.reset();
           digest.update(salt);
           byte[] input = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
           for (int i = 0; i < iterationNb; i++) {
               digest.reset();
               input = digest.digest(input);
           }
           return input;
       }

}
```

Using Spring Security base64 encoder.

Main Point: 
Both login and registration hashing and salting process looks the same but when testing in login page it isn't equal.

Comment: The above code is works fine when I test it . Is there any special situation when you getting not equal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem....

Password was not properly being sent to backend...